# Error while compiling Octave with GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, octave

While trying to compile Octave 4.0.3 using gcc 4.2.8 I get the following error

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/local/home/qa/joseph/app_porting/octave-porting/try_gcc_5.4.0/build_octave/src'
  GEN      mkoctfile.cc
  CXX      mkoctfile.o
  CXXLD    mkoctfile
  CC       octave-display-available.o
  GEN      main.cc
  CXX      octave-main.o
  CXXLD    octave
  CXX      main-cli.o
  CXXLD    octave-cli
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzungetc'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzwrite'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzread'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzgetc'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzflush'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzputc'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzclose'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gztell'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzseek'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzdopen'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'compress'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'uncompress'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzsetparams'
../libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: error: undefined reference to 'gzopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [octave-cli] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/local/home/qa/joseph/app_porting/octave-porting/try_gcc_5.4.0/build_octave/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/home/qa/joseph/app_porting/octave-porting/try_gcc_5.4.0/build_octave'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I missing any dependencies here? I have tried installing the following dependencies libpng-dev,zlib1g-dev but the error persists.

Comment: may be a known bug of octave 4.0.3., see http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?48407, solution would be to wait for new release, downgrade, patch or use the mercurial sources as commented in the issue tracker

Comment: +1 makedev. If this is indeed that bug, you should be able to build 4.0.2 just fine. Note that 4.0.3 was a patch release with very few changes so 4.0.2 might work fine for your needs.

Comment: Similar error in the `make` of **Octave 4.2.0** with gcc 6.3.0 --- In this case the error caught by `collect2` concerns several lines of type `libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to 'Magick::*` --- Development libraries `libmagick*-dev` had been installed. The configure stage had exited nicely