# Undefined reference to Magick when trying to build Octave with GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, octave, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to build Octave 4.2.2 on an Ubuntu 16.04 with GCC 4.9.3 but I get this error :

```
libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `Magick::CoderInfo::CoderInfo(std::string const&)'
libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::comment() const'
libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `Magick::CoderInfo::description() const'
libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::magick() const'
libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::attribute(std::string)'
libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::ping(std::string const&)'
```

I already checked my libs and that's what I have :

```
graphicsmagick/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed]
graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 all [installed]
imagemagick/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick-6.q16/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed]
libgraphics-magick-perl/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed]
libgraphicsmagick++1-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed]
libgraphicsmagick-q16-3/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed]
libgraphicsmagick1-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.6 amd64 [installed]
libmagick++-6-headers/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed,auto-removable]
libmagick++-6.q16-5v5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagick++-6.q16-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libmagickcore-6-arch-config/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6-headers/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-2/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
libmagickcore-6.q16-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6-headers/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-6.q16-2/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
libmagickwand-6.q16-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickwand-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed]
```

Moreover, I have checked liboctinterp.so :

```
ldd libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so | grep -i magick++
    libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12 => /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12 (0x00007f6c7fa2b000)

nm -C /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12 | grep -i coderinfo
    nm: /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12: no symbols

nm -D /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12 | grep -i coderinfo
000000000003e600 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoaSERKS0_
000000000003e650 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC1EPKN9MagickLib11_MagickInfoE
000000000003e350 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
000000000003e2c0 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC1ERKS0_
000000000003e280 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC1Ev
000000000003e650 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC2EPKN9MagickLib11_MagickInfoE
000000000003e350 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
000000000003e2c0 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC2ERKS0_
000000000003e280 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoC2Ev
000000000003e530 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoD1Ev
000000000003e530 T _ZN6Magick9CoderInfoD2Ev
000000000003e5d0 T _ZNK6Magick9CoderInfo10isReadableEv
000000000003e5e0 T _ZNK6Magick9CoderInfo10isWritableEv
000000000003e5a0 T _ZNK6Magick9CoderInfo11descriptionB5cxx11Ev
000000000003e5f0 T _ZNK6Magick9CoderInfo12isMultiFrameEv
000000000003e570 T _ZNK6Magick9CoderInfo4nameB5cxx11Ev
```

I have no idea why I got this error.

Thanks for your replies :)

EDIT : I already checked thousands of posts, including this one [Error while compiling Octave with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228019/error-while-compiling-octave-with-gcc) which is close to mine, but without any result.

EDIT2 : What I got if I check shared object dependencies with grep for `Magick` instead of `Magick++` :

```
ldd libinterp/.libs/liboctinterp.so | grep -i magick
    libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12 => /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick++-Q16.so.12 (0x00007f09ff71a000)
    libGraphicsMagick-Q16.so.3 => /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick-Q16.so.3 (0x00007f09ff1bf000)
```

And the command `nm` results with `nm: /usr/lib/libGraphicsMagick-Q16.so.3: no symbols` .

Comment: have you done `sudo apt build-dep octave` to begin with?

Comment: Not exactly because this command is not working on my system, but I checked the official instructions (https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems#The_right_way) and I have all the dependencies.

Comment: When you check the shared objects dependencies of `liboctinterp.so`, try to grep for `Magick` instead of `Magick++`. The C library should also appear there. Also, if you installed or updated graphicsmagick you may need to rerun `configure`.

Comment: @carandraug I edited my post about your advice

Comment: Did you try to rerun configure? Just to make sure, on a fresh untar of the source release, you do '/.configure && make' only?

Comment: Yes I did it twice. It didn't bring any change.

Comment: I found some reports online of similar issues as you. There's many things that may be causing but seems like rebuilding GraphicsMagick from source is a possible solution for them all. https://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick

Comment: I see, I will try this solution soon. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, the only solution was to rebuild GraphicsMagick.
I hope this post will help other people ! :)